# Upload: library file size limit?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, file-upload

I have **SharePoint Server 2010**, account on Office365 and iOS app.
I need to upload 100KB, 500KB, 5MB, 50MB files on server via HTTP (not browser).
I've successfully uploaded 100KB to my SP via HTTP (PUT, POST), but uploading 144KB fails with connection failure. Same thing with all files >= 100KB.
What should I check in SP configuration to see if it has uploading file-size limit equals to 100KB?

P.S.: I've successfully uploaded all the files on Office365 with the same iOS app.

Comment: There is a maximum file upload size configuration in Central Admin, but it defaults to 50 MB. So, if you didn't change this it probably isn't the issue, but I'd check on it. It's on the "Web Application General Settings" page.

Comment: Yes, maxRequestLength="51200" in web.config, so it equals to 50MB.

Comment: Can you upload >100kb to the server natively via the browser?

Comment: Yes, I can upload file of any size up to 50MB via the browser, @JesusShelby.